# JQuery Mobile “Error Loading Page” on 404 and 500

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile, http-status-code-404

I would like jQuery mobile to navigate to pages if they are marked with 500 or 404. Is there a way to let jqm know that these pages are okay to navigate to? I have seen other solutions that redirect to a 404 page using `$( document ).bind( "pageloadfailed")` but I don't want to do this. I just want to display the 404\500 page generated by my PHP application. Thanks.

Comment: I think this will answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622729/jquerymobile-get-result-of-pageloadfailed

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Mobile knows that HTTP Status Codes 404 & 500 are error codes and so will automatically execute its default error behavior unless you specifically tell it to do otherwise. The [jQuery Mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html) state about the `pageloadfailed` event:

> By default, after dispatching this event, the framework will display a page failed message and call `reject()` on the deferred object contained within the event's data object. Callbacks can prevent this default behavior from executing by calling `preventDefault()` on the event.

So...the default behavior is to hijack your request and show its own "page failed message." The *only* way to get something besides the default behavior is to override the default setting. You *do* have to write an event handler for the `pageloadfailed` event, but you don't have to redirect to a different 404 page, you can just use the HTML that came back from your app. You can stop the default behavior with the aptly-named method `preventDefault()`. This tells jQuery that you will handle the error yourself - and here you can simply pass along the HTML that your app returned to be displayed. Again, from the docs:

> Callbacks that call `preventDefault()` on the event, **MUST** call `resolve()` or `reject()` on this object so that `changePage()` requests resume processing.

Here is code that calls `resolve()` so you can pass in the HTML to display:

```js
$( document ).bind( "pageloadfailed", function( event, data ) {

    // Let the framework know we're going to handle things.
    event.preventDefault();

    // at some point, either in this callback, or through
    // some other async means, call resolve, passing in
    // the following args, plus a jQuery collection object
    // containing the DOM element for the page.

    // Extract the HTML response from the Ajax request
    var page = data.xhr.responseText;

    data.deferred.resolve( data.absUrl, data.options, page );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Mikes answer, which nearly resolved that issue to me, you have to add the error page to your pageContainer structure.

For example:

```
$( document ).on( "pageloadfailed", function( event, data ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var page = $( data.xhr.responseText );

    // make sure that the content is displayed
    $.mobile.pageContainer.append( page );

    data.deferred.resolve( data.absUrl, data.options, page );
});
```